# What is best way to develop iptables module

Tags: c, linux, module, iptables

I've iptv provider, that deliver video via encrypted with private key udp multicast traffic.
This time stream decoded with patched version of udp2http proxy. I want to develop iptables module to decrypt packets "on the fly", because iptv channel swtich on my tv is faster on udp streams, rather then http (and get some experience writing iptables modules).

There are two ways to do that (i think)

1. Write decryption algorithm in module itself
2. Write module to send data to user space, write daemon to decrypt packets, and send packet back to filter.

First will be faster, Second - more safe for system (because of delays in network stack could decrease overall system performance), and could be have more features, easy debug and so on.

Which way will be best ?
Which pros and cons in each way ?

Comment: What does a iptables module has to do with video streaming and decoding? You better use iptables to simply divert the TCP (or HTTP) traffic from your application to a new one, which will then re-send it as UDP. Doesn't that solve your problem?

Comment: jweyrich: It should XOR each byte of packet with each byte of private key, and send result packet to client.
Yes, I could add "additional" proxy to back conversion http to udp. But it is additional instance.

Comment: Yet, much, much simpler! Unless all you're after is the experience in writing modules for iptables. Which I should not discourage you :-) But in this case I can't give much help.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a user space program using netfilter queue would be a better option, as the solution can be quickly developed (without reboots) and also you can test the performance.